# Are Eiffel tower visits restricted due to COVID?

Tags: france, covid-19, paris

Are General visitors allowed to travel to the Top of the Eiffel Tower (Roof) by Lift/Elevator? Are there restrictions due to COVID?

Comment: What did their website tell you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Eiffel Tower reopened to fully vaccinated visitors [in July](https://www.toureiffel.paris/en/news/visit/covid-19-pass-sanitaire-and-protection-measures-eiffel-tower); the lift to the top (summit) is an option. All visitors are required to present the “Pass Sanitaire” (Health Pass) upon entry.